# 新しいMacを買った時に移行すべき最小のデータは？

Tags: macos

TimeMachineで外部HDDにバックアップを取っています。
新しいMacを買った際に以前はまるごと移行していましたが、Mac AppStoreやDropBox、iCloudなどが登場した事で移行すべきデータがどんどん少なくなって来たように思います。

新しいMacを買った際に移行するデータを最小にするよい方法があれば教えてください。

Comment: [この質問はトピックスに沿った質問ですか？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: 質問者様は[理解者バッジ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed)を持っておられないようですが、[ツアー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)はご一読なされましたか？

Comment: こちらは同様の質問も英語にありますしトピックスに沿っていると思います。

Comment: そうですか。英語の方にリンクが有ればと思うのですが…
データを最小にする**圧縮方法**となればアルゴリズムの質問ですが、OSの利用法やデータの選別方法に関する質問のように感じられプログラミングと関係があるのか疑問でした。

Comment: 確かにプログラミングそのものではないですが、開発環境として使われますしタグもあるのでグレーゾーンではないでしょうか。

Comment: では、私が開発環境の整ったWindowsを利用していてデスクトップとマイフォルダの使い分けを質問をしてもグレーゾーンだと言うことですね。
[ひとまず海外を調べてみました。](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx)
クローズになっていないものは**[環境変数の設定](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)**や**[開発環境のインストール](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)**や**[OS付属の開発環境のバージョン情報](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower)**や**[エディタとキーのとすり合わせ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127591/using-caps-lock-as-esc-in-mac-os-x)**です。

Comment: グレーゾーンの質問ではありますが「実際的で回答可能な問題である」と思いますし、スタックオーバーフロー自体がパブリックベータの段階ですので、あまり質問の範囲を狭めすぎるのもどうかと思っています。ということで、まずはオープンのままでお願いします。さらに討議が必要という場合にはメタへの投稿を宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time Machineのバックアップサイズをなるべく小さくするのであれば、ユーザフォルダのデータをDropBoxやiCloudなどに全部置いてしまえば、設定ファイルなどを持つ ~/Library 以外のデータはすべて復元時に不要になると思います。
では、Time Machineのバックアップにあるオプションで「除外」してもいいのかと言われると、実はそうでもなくて

- Time Machineからデータ戻したほうが一般的にはネット経由よりも時間が短い
- システムごとTime Machineバックアップを取っておくと緊急用起動ディスクになる（10.8以降）
- Time Machineはスナップショットバックアップなので、過去消してしまったファイルも復旧できる

などのメリットがあります。最近のOS Xは復元時に移行アシスタントでユーザフォルダの中も「どれを戻すか」をチェックボックス形式で選択できるようになりましたので、バックアップは丸ごと、復元時にその時必要なものだけ戻すのが運用上安全だと思います。

Comment: なるほど復旧にかかる時間については盲点でした。

Comment: そうなんです。ビルド変えてテストしているマシンが1台あって、週に何度かリストアしてデータ復元する作業をしているんですが、戻す時間が最大のボトルネックですね。OS Xのインストールは数GBなので最近は10分でクリーンインストールできる良い時代になりましたが…。

Answer (score 3):

> Mac AppStoreやDropBox、iCloudなどが登場した事で移行すべきデータがどんどん少なくなって来た

と書かれているように、次のような基本指針が立つと思います。

- ソースコードは全て[GitHub](https://github.com)や[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)へ
- メディアデータは専用のクラウドサービスへ (例: 写真はGoogle+ Photoへ)
- それ以外のファイルは汎用の共有サービスへ (Dropbox、SugarSyncほか)

上記から外れてしまうものが「移行の最小データ」と考えると、以下に集約できるでしょうか。

1. GUIアプリケーションの設定
2. [Dotfiles](https://dotfiles.github.io/) (`.atom`, `.emacs.d`ほか)
3. 機密情報: SSH鍵、パスワード、アプリケーションライセンス

1について、`~/Library/Preferences`, `~/Library/Application Support`にそのほとんどが置かれています。設定によっては、`defaults`コマンドから[セット可能なものも多い](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx)です(↓例: Safariの開発者メニュー表示)。

```
$ defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true
```

設定ではなく、アプリケーションデータが`~/Library/`に置かれるケースは、Dropboxにデータを移動してシンボリックリンクを貼ることで追い出せるケースがあります。ですので、理想的なケースではGUIアプリケーション設定をバックアップ対象から外すことができます。

最近のDotfilesは、元々の意味合いを離れて、環境復元ツールとしての性格が強まっています。デスクトップアプリをインストールする[cask](http://caskroom.io/)コマンドも人気ですね。

結論です。少々極端ですが、プログラマとしては

- Dotfiles
- 機密情報

を「移行の最小データ」として目指すのはどうでしょうか。

(参考まで、[先日作成した私のDotfilesはこちら](https://github.com/cognitom/dotfiles)に置いてあります)

Answer (score 1):

開発環境を整える点に関しては、他の回答者様もおっしゃっているように、かつてのBrewfileなるシェルスクリプトを予め作成しておくことをオススメします。

homebrew、gem、npm、vagrant plugin、その他をいっぺんに入れられるのは非常に便利です。またbrew-caskを利用すればGUIアプリケーションも同時にインストールできます。ただXcodeを含め、App Storeで配布されているGUIアプリケーションに関しては手動で行う必要があります。